# How to use golang exec scutil to monitor the macos network change

Tags: macos, go, networking, command-line, interface

I already find the command `(echo -e "n.add State:/Network/Global/IPv4\nn.watch" & cat) | scutil`
but I can not run it in Golang. It's worded on terminal

I would like to know how to output the results to chanels

Comment: How have you tried running it from your Go code? Generally, the answer to "how do I run a command in Go?" is "use the [exec package](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec)."

Comment: I try the "exec" package. But it was not working, maybe because the `scutil` need a pty environment to catch its output.

Comment: There is a [`pty`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/creack/pty) package that might be of interest.